# Any optimization in creating protobuf callback

Tags: c++, callback, rpc, proto, protobuf-c

I just started to do some rpc releating things.

When creating a async call, I have to call a `NewCallback`
For example

```
  // See Closure.
  template <typename Class, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
  inline Closure* NewCallback(Class* object, void (Class::*method)(Arg1, Arg2),
                              Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
    return new internal::MethodClosure2<Class, Arg1, Arg2>(
      object, method, true, arg1, arg2);
  }
```

Inside the `NewCallback` call, it create a MethodClosure object, its' ctor and run methods is:

```
    MethodClosure2(Class* object, MethodType method, bool self_deleting,
                   Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
      : object_(object), method_(method), self_deleting_(self_deleting),
        arg1_(arg1), arg2_(arg2) {}

    void Run() override {
      bool needs_delete = self_deleting_;  // read in case callback deletes
      (object_->*method_)(arg1_, arg2_);
      if (needs_delete) delete this;
    }
```

So, as I understand, the arg1 and arg2 is copied 3 times when creating the `NewCallback` object with below code. And extra 1 time in `(object_->*method_)(arg1_, arg2_);`.

```
int a; 
std::shared_ptr<string> s; 
NewCallback(this, func1, a, s);
```

Even if i use move semantic, there are still 3 times copy and 1 time move for a full async call. (Twice for creating NewCallback, and rest for real call of the callback function.)

```
int a
std::shared_ptr<string> s;
NewCallback(this, func1, a, std::move(s));
```

The primitive type and pointer are ok, but shared pointer is really expensive, I made a little experiment in my laptop, it takes 1s per 10k times copy.

So my question are,

1. Is my understanding about times of 'times of object copy' correct?
2. Shall I concern on this? Or should I only use primitive type or raw pointer in the callback to avoid the expensive copy?
3. If this is right to concern, maybe I can optimize the call with std::move or std::forward to reduce copy times.